# Localize text in re-authentication popup

Tags: facebook, internationalization, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-authentication

When trying to force a re-authentication, I always get the following information message in the Facebook login popup :

> The page you are trying to visit on ... requires that you re-enter your password.

This is perfectly correct...as long as you want to display this text in English.
My problem is that I would like to localize this value.

After some tries, it seems that changing the primary language of the app or the connect url (tested with //connect.facebook.net/de_DE/all.js and //connect.facebook.net/fr_FR/all.js) does not have any effect.

Any idea on how to achieve this ?

Comment: There’s a good chance this happens just because there simply _is_ no translation for that yet. As long as FB does not have a translation for this stored, the message will be shown in English. Btw., careful with using re-authentication client-side – it does not look as if they have fixed this bug yet: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/248632218597467

Comment: Thanks for the information about this bug, but I already noticed it and found a way to solve this using the auth_nonce.

Comment: I found a german translation in the [Translations admin panel](https://www.facebook.com/translations/admin/dashboard.php)

Answer (score 1):

Have your tried what they say on the facebook-api page?

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/#localization

And this:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/internationalization/

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant when I wrote that I tried with //connect.facebook.net/de_DE/all.js and //connect.facebook.net/fr_FR/all.js

Comment: function(d){
  var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
  js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/de_DE/all.js";
  d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
}

Comment: function facebookLogin(fbParameters, context) {
  FB.login(function(loginResponse) {
    ...
  }, fbParameters);
}

Comment: fbParameters looks like this : {scope: 'email', auth_type: 'reauthenticate', auth_nonce: '8142151c-7334-4190-bb68-3bf7ebccae1d'}